# Replace parts of a string in Java

Tags: java

I need to replace parts of a string by looking up the System properties.

For example, consider the string **It was {var1} beauty killed {var2}**

I need to parse the string, and replace all the words contained within the parenthesis by looking up their value in System properties. If System.getProperty() returns null, then simply replace with empty character. This is pretty straightforward  when I know the variables well ahead. But the string that I need to parse is not defined ahead. I wouldn't know how many number of variables are in the string and what the variable names are. Assuming a simple, well formatted string (no nested parenthesis, open - close matches), what is the simplest or the most elegant way to parse through the string and replace all the character sequences that are enclosed in the parenthesis?

Only solution I could come up with is to traverse the string from the first character, note down the positions of the start and end positions of the parenthesis, replace the string between them, and then continue until reaching the end of the string. Is there simpler way to do this?

Comment: Are you aware of the `replace` and `replaceAll` methods of the `String` class?

Comment: @DavidWallace yes I'm aware. Are you aware that the first argument to those methods is the character sequence that should be replaced? My question was about how to find all the sequences in the original string that need to be replaced

Comment: Well, no, the first argument to `replaceAll` is a regular expression.  Are you able to encapsulate the strings that you're trying to replace in a suitable regular expression?  And I asked the question so that I know what kind of level to pitch an answer at.

Comment: @DavidWallace   only thing guaranteed is that variables will be wrapped in parenthesis. So the reqular expression needs to find all such parts of the string. And even if I come up with such expression, how exactly would I use that in replaceAll()?  In my example string above, if the regex can identify the two variables var1 and var2, the requirement is to look up the values for these two variables independently and use them.. how exactly would replaceAll() will help when it takes only one word to replace with?

Comment: Well, you could either iterate through all your variables and call `replace` for each.  Or maybe you need to use a `Matcher` to iterate through the matches of your regular expression and look up each of them individually in whatever data structure you've got your variables in.

Comment: Is the placeholder format a strict requirement? If you are just looking for replacing placeholder with keyword, there are existing library you may make use of

Answer (score 0):

You can use the parentheses to break the initial string into substrings, and then replace every other substring.

```
String[] substituteValues = {"the", "str", "other", "another"};
int substituteValuesIndex = 0;

String test = "Here is {var1} string called {var2}";

// split the string up into substrings
test = test.replaceAll("\\}", "\\{");
String[] splitString = test.split("\\{");

// now sub in your values
for (int k=1; k < splitString.length; k = k+2) {
    splitString[k] = substituteValues[substituteValuesIndex];
    substituteValuesIndex++;
}

String result = "";
for (String s : splitString) {
    result = result + s;
}
```